# How to terminate Cloud Function Firestore Trigger after Query then write

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I'm kinda new to Cloud Functions, Typescript, and Async/await syntax. What im trying to do is on my Cloud Function, I want to observe Firestore's onCreate, then i will perform a query and observe using onSnapshot (not get), and after the query, perform a write operation. All these are being done already but there's something wrong. It takes like 1-2 minutes before the write operation happens. I'm pretty sure it's due to async/ await issues. I have watched several tutorials, but I wasn't able to find specific that could fix the issue. On code below, given are, there are three collections (collectionA, collectionB, collectionC) and collectionB has a document 'TestDocumentID'. Also, im not sure where & how to call the 'unsubscribe' function. Thank you very much in advance.

```
export const onCreateItem = functions.firestore
.document('collectionA/{uid}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  return firestore.collection('collectionB').doc('TestDocumentID')
    .onSnapshot(result => {

    const test =  { 'test': 'asd' };

    return firestore.collection('collectionC').doc().set(test);
  });
});`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `onSnapshot()` in Cloud Functions.  Adding a persistent listener like that is certainly not what you want to do.  Also, `onSnapshot()` doesn't return a promise, so the return value you're providing from the function isn't going to be meaningful to Cloud Functions.

Instead, you should use `get()` to query Firestore.  It returns a promise, and you can use that to continue your work, and tell Cloud Functions when all of the work is complete.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have watched ur tutorials. thanks. I didn't see any documentation that warns me not to use onSnapShot() in Cloud functions, is there any?. Also, if I overlooked it in your tutorials, please let me know. I accepted the answer, and seems I just have to call onSnapshot on client side. On my use case, I need to use onSnapshot, not get.

Comment: can i use runTransaction instead in cloud function? If so, how would the return statement look like?

Comment: @user7888262 yes you can but if you are using it just to increment a value better to use `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(NUMBER_TO_INCREMENT)`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the delay has something to do with the [cold start](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips). What do you mean by unsubscribe? Usually when a task is completed whether it fails due to error/timeout or succeed the function is immediately terminated as well, thus you do not need to remove the snapshot listener anymore unlike its mobile or web SDK.

Also I don't recall any `.onSnapshot()` exist in Cloud Function of Firestore and if there is, probably that is not the best thing to do based on your given sample. Make sure to always check first the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events), its well written and has a lot of code snippet to play with.

Comment: About cold start. 
Im not too familiar with cold start, but based on my basic search, one example of it is, 'The very first cold start happens when the first request comes in after deployment.' . I dont think this is the case for me, because I have been trying for several times for several hours already.
About unsubscribe.
I thought onSnapshot returns a promise(just like get), but based on @Doug Stevenson 's answer, I doesn't and I should'nt use onSnapshot on cloud function.
About onSnapshot usage.
It exists in Cloud function. Maybe I just have to use it on client side instead.

Comment: Yes, what he said is right its probably not the thing you really wanted to do since you technically you don't need to listen in real-time after the invocation of the onCreate, onWrite, etc of the function. All real-time listening should already and only at that point and while inside of the function you use get() if you want to perform query.

Comment: Remember not to create a nested real-time listener just like in your sample. Even in client side, all listener should be separated not nested.